# Pass array from php to Java (android) via JSON

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

I need to know how to pass an array from php to java.
I can do the opposite thing: passing an array from java to php, but I dont know how to do the opposite.
The code that i wrote is that:

```
`//php script
$response["success"] = 1;
$Id = {"1", "2"};
$response["Id"] = $Id;
echo json_encode($response);
`

//in java
int success = json.getInt("success");

ArrayList <Integer> Id = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("Id");
                if (jsonArray != null) { 
                       int len = jsonArray.length();
                       for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
                        Id.add(jsonArray.getInt(i));
                       } 
                    }
```

On my script I pass several things to my android app, and I'm using the same json object to pass them.
Should I use different json objects, one for some things and another for the array using a jsonarray? (the tag "success" is passed with no issues).

the only error I get is this: `sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`
But I think is something about the layout, so no matter with the question.

Comment: show code of sendUserActionEvent

Comment: Sir, which is the function of sendUserActionEvent?

Comment: you getting error in sendUserActionEvent, then you have to show the code of that function,